# Syntax error with IF EXISTS UPDATE ELSE INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, insert, exists

I'm using MySQL 5.1 hosted at my ISP. This is my query

```
mysql_query("
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM licensing_active WHERE title_1='$title_1') THEN
    BEGIN
        UPDATE licensing_active SET time='$time' WHERE title_1='$title_1')
    END ELSE BEGIN
        INSERT INTO licensing_active(title_1) VALUES('$title_1')
    END   
") or die(mysql_error());
```

The error is

```
... check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM licensing_active WHERE title_1='Title1') THEN ' at line 1
```

My actual task involves

```
WHERE title_1='$title_1' AND title_2='$title_2' AND version='$version' ...ETC...
```

but I have reduced it down to make things simpler for my problem solving

In my searches on this, I keep seeing references to 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE', but don't know what to do with that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is a simple and easy solution, try it.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM licensing_active WHERE title_1 ='$title_1' ");

if( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE licensing_active SET time = '$time' WHERE title_1 = '$title_1' ");
}
else
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO licensing_active (title_1) VALUES ('$title_1') ");
}
```

*Note: Though this question is from 2012, keep in mind that **mysql_*** functions are no longer available since PHP 7.*

Comment: That works for me, thanks.  And seems straightforward to understand and remember.  It might not be super-efficient, but this isn't yet a high traffic application so I'm sure this method will be fine for a year or more.  Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

This should do the trick for you:

```
insert into 
    licensing_active (title_1, time) 
    VALUES('$title_1', '$time') 
    on duplicate key 
        update set time='$time'
```

This is assuming that `title_1` is a unique column (enforced by the database) in your table.

The way that `insert... on duplicate` works is it tries to insert a new row first, but if the insert is rejected because a key stops it, it will allow you to update certain fields instead.

Comment: Hi Fluffeh.  title_1 is not unique.  The only unique column I have is an int named id.  It is set as 'auto_increment', 'unique' and 'primary'.  I don't access it directly.  Am still struggling with the same error.

Comment: Couldn't quite get there, so I did the logic in PHP - as described by Dark Wish.  Thanks though.

Comment: works for me when I remove `set` at the end. i.e. `INSERT INTO <table> (col1, col2) VALUES('f1','f2') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2='fn'`

Comment: Just remember to use WHERE clause!!! From here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp `The WHERE clause specifies which record or records that should be updated. If you omit the WHERE clause, all records will be updated!`

Comment: @BamsBamx: This is all one `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of your query is wrong. Checkout http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Use the on `duplicate key syntax` to achieve the result you want. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO licensing_active (title_1) VALUES ('$title_1')"; 
if(!$link->query($insertQuery)){ // Insert fails, so update
    $updateQuery = "UPDATE licensing_active SET time='$time' WHERE title_1='$title_1'";
    $link->query($updateQuery);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example I tried and its works fine:

```
INSERT INTO user(id, name, address) VALUES(2, "Fadl", "essttt") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = "kahn ajab", address = "Address is test"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

I am amazed to see so many useless codes and answers...
Just replace **INSERT** with **REPLACE**.

¯\*(ツ)*/¯

Comment: The answer could have been provided without attitude, which is not required or helpful.